# Linear law: how to determine three unknown constants from a non-linear equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

[image]

**Question**:

The diagram shows part of a straight line graph drawn to represent the equation $y=\frac{ax^2+b}{cx}$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are integers. Given that the line passes through $(4,9)$ and has gradient $-\frac{1}{4}$, find

(i) the value of $\frac{y}{x}$ where the straight line cuts the horizontal axis, and

(ii) the value of $a$, of $b$ and of $c$.

**Attempt**:

(i)

$$Y=mX+c$$
Gradient, $m=-\frac{1}{4}$

At $(4,9)$,
$$9=-\frac{1}{4}(4)+c$$
$$c=10$$

Therefore, $Y=-\frac{1}{4}X+10$

When $Y=0$,

$$0=-\frac{1}{4}(X)+10$$
$$X=40$$

Since $X=\frac{x}{y}$, therefore $\frac{y}{x}=\frac{1}{40}$.

Is my solution correct?

(ii)

$$y=\frac{ax^2+b}{cx}$$

Divide the equation by $y$,

$$1=\frac{ax}{cy}+\frac{b}{cxy}$$
$$\frac{b}{cxy}=1-\frac{ax}{cy}$$
$$\frac{1}{xy}=-\frac{a}{b}\frac{x}{y}+\frac{c}{b}$$

Since $Y=-\frac{1}{4}X+10$,
$$-\frac{a}{b}=-\frac{1}{4}$$
$$\frac{c}{b}=10$$

After this step, I do not know how to continue. I have two equations, but three unknowns. How do I get a third equation so that I can solve for $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Any suggestions / help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The equation $y=\frac{ax^2+b}{cx}$ can be written as
$ax^2-cxy+b=0$.

As you mentioned, $Y=-\frac{1}{4}X+10$
or $x^2-40xy+4 = 0$, by replacing $Y = \frac{1}{xy}, X = \frac{x}{y}$.

So, $a = 1, b = 4, c = 40$.

Comment: Thank you very much!